# Is it possible to send an email through Word mail button with default mail application?

Tags: windows-8, email, microsoft-word

When I try on a Windows 8 computer to send a Word document as an email attachment by clicking the mail button in Microsoft Word, I get first an error that no application has been assigned to handle this action.

After that comes an error message that there has been somehow a MAPI problem.

**Q:** Is it possible in Windows 8 with the default mail application to send a Microsoft Word document as an attachment by clicking the mail button in the Microsoft Word application?

Comment: which version of Word?

Comment: What email application?

Answer (score 1):

When you choose to send the word file by Email it checks the Outlook Express or Microsoft Outlook for mail setup. If your Outlook Express or Microsoft Outlook is not configured then it will show error message. If you are using webmail then just use the ATTACH FILE option in the COMPOSE or WRITE Mail.